# Primitive #define understanding in C

Tags: c++, c

I have a macro defined in C something like this:

```
  #define SOME_FIELD(_A_,_B_,_C_) \
    MyObj[ ## _A_ ## ].somePTR =        \
    (DWORD_PTR) (buff_ ## _C_  ## _C_ ## _ ## _B_ ## );
```

What i can understand that for index *A* we are getting some value for "somePTR". My question is, What is `## <name> ##` notation for and with this how value of somePTR is calculated??

I am new to such a macro so a descriptive explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: Why not just make an example and check the preprocessor output? `gcc -E` etc.

Comment: I hope that those are not the actual names of the params and the macro... if so the author needs some compassion training.

Comment: @Dennis - These are not actual names and this macro is a simplified form of a horrid looking macro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is called [token concatenation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_macro#Token_concatenation). It allows you to glue arguments together.

For your example, `SOME_FIELD(Param1,Param2,Param3);` expands like this:

```
MyObj[Param1].somePTR = (DWORD_PTR) (buff_Param3Param3_Param2);
```

It's easy enough to try this out yourself by using your compiler's pre-processor. You don't generally need to go to the trouble of writing a fully-fledged C program—the pre-processor can generally be invoked by itself.

Answer (score 1):

That's preprocessor token pasting

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y(v=vs.80).aspx

It will copy the actual parameter token as a string literal, so read it like

```
 // preprocessor_token_pasting.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#define paster( n ) printf_s( "token" #n " = %d", token##n )
int token9 = 9;

int main()
{
   paster(9);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the ## is [concatenation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_macro#Token_concatenation) primitive, it's used to create nwe symbols.

It's useful to create names in macro:

```
#define GENERIC_GETTER(f,g) (g->member_ ## f )
```

`GENERIC_GETTER(a,b)` will create `(b->member_a)` (new symbol created). If you don't use sharp-sharp, it would create `(b->member_ a)` (not glued together)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the `##` operator concatenates two tokens: it requires a legal
token on the left and a legal token on the right, and results in a new
token.  In your case, the first line in the macro 
(`MyObj[&nbsp;##&nbsp;_A_&nbsp;##&nbsp;].somePtr&nbsp;=&nbsp;\`) is
illegal, and results in undefined behavior.  Most implementations just
concatenate the strings, then retokenize once they've finished all of
the substitutions, so it will work, but it's not guaranteed.  And as far
as I can tell here, it's not necessary.  In the second line, on the
other hand, you are generating a new token.  If you invoke the macro:

```
SOME_FIELD(x,y,z);
```

it will expand to:

```
MyObj[x].somePtr = (DWORD_PTR)(buff_zzy);
```

(I might add that the use of symbols like `_A_`, `_B_` and `_C_` is also
undefined behavior.  A symbol starting with an underscore followed by a
capital letter is in the namespace of the implementation.)

Comment: You pointed out many things rightly. Thanks for the time you took explaining them.